# when is it あと and when is it ご?

Tags: readings, parsing

This sentence uses hiragana

しばらく**あと**で雪【ゆき】の中【なか】から見【み】つかる人【ひと】も多【おお】くいます

*Many people are found in the snow a while later.*

https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10013468931000/k10013468931000.html

so I thought this sentence might also be read with **あと**

大学【だいがく】を卒業後【そつぎょうご】、海外【かいがい】で働【はたら】きながら英語力【えいごりょく】を養【やしな】った

*After graduating from university, she worked abroad to develop her English skills.*

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPCK4VJFP7ZUTIL06K.html?iref=comtop_Edu_05

but this word seems to be a fixed three kanji term (wwwjdic):

卒業後 【そつぎょうご】 after graduation

Could this sentence possibly be read this way, or is a reading of **あと** grammatically out of the question?

大学【だいがく】を卒業後【そつぎょうあと】、海外【かいがい】で働【はたら】きながら英語力【えいごりょく】を養【やしな】った

Answer (score 1):

後 is read as ご when it's directly attached to a noun, and as あと when it's not.

Therefore you would have to write 卒業の後 in order for 後 to be read as あと.

Comment: でも「その後」は大抵「ご」ですね……。

Comment: 言われてみれば確かにそうですね！しかし、「その後【ご】」だけではないでしょうか？「後」をそういう風に読むのは。